# Jquery check if li with id=x exists in ul already

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable

I have many UL with li. Different UL will have li with the same id:

```
<ul>
 <li id='1'>this</li>
 <li id='2'>that</li>
</ul>

<ul>
 <li id='1'>this</li>
</ul>
```

The user can drag li from on list to the other but only if the li with the same id does not exist. So far I have this:

```
$(".container").droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var a = $(this).find("li").attr("id", $(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
            if (a.length == 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    ...
                });
            }                
        }
    });
```

However when I drop the draggable it changes the id of all li to the value of the dropped li.

Any guidance would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `attr()`, you're actually setting the `id` attribute of any elements matched by your `find()` call. You should use `find` on the ID you're matching against.

```
$(".container").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        var a = $(this).find("#" + $(ui.draggable).attr('id'));
        if (a.length === 0) {
            $.ajax({
                ...
            });
        }                
    }
});
```

Also, as @Diodeus mentions, IDs should not start with a number. They should also be unique document-wide, so if you need duplicate/expect IDs, I'd recommend using a different attribute, such as an HTML5 data attribute: http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Answer (score 7):

IDs cannot start with numbers and must be unique. For non-unique identifiers, use classes.

You can check to see if an element exists like this:

```
if($('#myDIV').length) {

}
```

Comment: Diodeus, I only want to check within the one list (The droppable container) not the whole page

Comment: @abarr - What Diodeus means is you cannot duplicate IDs on your page. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2